# how to remove magento customer account dashboard link

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

please Help Me 
how to remove magento  **rwd theme** customer account dashboard link and set some specific links only in **magento**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For remove magento customer account dashboard link from the rwd theme follow below steps :

1. Go to app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout - customer.xml
2. find "Account Dashboard" word in the file and it around line no. 235.
3. Comment or remove code. like below code :
   `<action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer">
      <name>account</name>
      <path>customer/account/</path>
      <label>Account Dashboard</label>
   </action>`
4. And if you want add new link then replace that code with your custom link which you want to put link.
5. Save file and Clear cache and check frontend in the custom account.